# *bool in golang

Tags: go

While working on CRUD operations with Mongo I came across the below piece of code. The find query option needs to be pass in **FIND** func.

Per my understanding, it's just a flag. How can we pass a **pointer** to it and also what does it mean?

```
type FindOptions struct {
    AllowPartialResults *bool
}
```

Resolved it using below func but it doesn't makes any sense.

```
options.FindOptions{
    AllowPartialResults: func() *bool {
        var a bool = true
        return &a
    }(),
}
```

Comment: Same as a `*int` or `*byte` or any other pointer type - what is it about a bool pointer specifically that you're unsure about?

Comment: As I have already mentioned ** AllowPartialResults** is a flag of type *bool. why we can't be use type bool there. @adrian

Comment: Because pointer and value types are not interchangeable. Or are you asking why the library uses `*bool` instead of `bool`?

Comment: ya exactly, why have we used *bool instead of bool ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library uses a pointer to a bool to distinguish between the following three cases:

- Option not set by application (field is nil)
- Option is set to true by application (field is pointer to true)
- Option is set to false by application (field is pointer to false).

The mongo package provides helper functions and methods for initializing options.  Here's how to use these helpers to create the FindOptions shown in the question:

```
options.Find().SetAllowPartialResults(true)
```